# file_get_contents() only works on google.com and youtube.com

Tags: php, file-get-contents

file_get_contents() only works on google.com and youtube.com but it doesn't even work on my domains. This is the error i'm getting.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(oneofmydomains.com/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vhosts/oneofmydomains.com/subdomains/search/httpdocs/index.php on line 28
```

I also added `php_value allow_url_fopen On` and `allow_url_fopen = On` to my htacces and php.ini.

Why can I get the contents of google and youtube but almost none of the other domains on the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems, your hosting provider disable access to other domains, except of several "white" domains. This restraint is applied on free hostings

Comment: Just tested this on a local machine, it does work there indeed. seems my hosting provider does block access. I pay 40 dollars a year for this domain sad enough.

Comment: Hosting and domain are two different things. Maybe, you have paid for the domain, but use a free hosting?

Comment: Ye sorry I meant hosting.